# Send POST request via AJAX to same page and get value using $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

This is puzzling me and I can't find anything telling what is wrong...

I'm sending a value to a function, and using **AJAX** to send this value through a **POST request to the same page**. Then, on success, I'm **loading a .php file** in this page and I want to **retrieve** the posted value using **$_POST['campId']**.

```
function post(value) {

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: {'campId': value},
       success: function () {
           navigateTo.push.newCampaign();
       }
   });
}

$.each(jsonObj, function (key, value) {
    $(value).on('click', function () {
         post(value);
    })
});
```

Then on `newCampaign.php` (the page I'm loading), I'm testing if the `POST` is working:

```
console.log(<?php print($_POST['campId']); ?>); //This don't show anything
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?> // and this brings an empty array: "array(0) {}"
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get the posted value?

Comment: you dont have `url` for the ajax request also where did you do the `console.log`?

Comment: I don't have the url because i'm loading on the same page, and the console.log is written in the page I'm loading

Comment: Do you have to load the same page? What is the reason for that?

Comment: I'm not loading the same page, I'm doing a SPA, so I'm sending the POST to another file that will be loaded without refreshing the current page

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you are posting the value on the same page. Now if you want to get post values on any other page, then post the values on that respective page
For eg. Add this attribute in ajax code url: "newCampaign.php" and then test for the post values on newCampaign page